# Why or how does an invalid callback url work with Oauth2 in Postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

All other steps of OAuth2 are clear to me except the concept of the re-direct URL.

I am querying an API end-point (Bitbucket) via Postman. When registering my application with Bitbucket, it asks me for a redirect end-point. I puzzled over this for a while and tried a random URL - https://random-appxxxx.com/

In Postman, if I entered all the info correctly (client id,secret,access-token URL etc.) along with that random URL, it works perfectly and I am not sure why that is. If I understand correctly, the redirect URL (i.e. callback URL) is where the user is directed to after the client application is authorized.

So, how does Postman read the code from the redirected URL - https://random-appxxxx.com/?code={random string} since the authorization server is sending the code to an invalid url ?

Answer (score 4):

For an Auth 2.0 code flow you need to make an [Authorization Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) and then [Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3).
Postman acts as a browser, a redirect response after Authorization Request from the server is the same as a response of a post request after the Access Token Request.
Postman calls the Auth URL you defined and expect a response of redirect to `callbackURL?code=auth_code`.
Then call the Access Token URL with that `auth_code` like described in the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

Postman doesn't need to call the redirect URL because he finish the handshake instead of your server.